# Send objects from/to Java using GWT

Tags: java, google-app-engine, gwt, google-cloud-datastore

To learn GWT and Google AppEngine (GAE) I'm trying to create a simple application using GWT with two or three objects (entities). In this application one object, let's say **Student**, encapsulates ArrayList of other objects, say **Classes** and **Books**. Then it creates list of Students and sends it to Java code on GAE and stores it to the data store.

Question: *is it possible to do this kind of stuff using GWT + GAE + Google DataStore? Are there any examples/tutorials of using all these technologies at once?*

Is it even worth it to use this tech. stack at this point?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I would suggest the following:

1. Run through the [GWT StockWatcher Tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/gettingstarted.html).  If you haven't already, this will help you with the basics of GWT.
2. Continue with the [GWT and App Engine Tutorial](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/tutorials/1.6/appengine.html).  This will show you how to modify the StockWatcher code to work with the Google App Engine and store simple data types in Google DataStore.
3. Finally, follow the steps I outlined in this [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958879/problems-passing-class-objects-through-gwt-rpc/962823#962823).  This will show you how to modify StockWatcher code further to return an ArrayList of Stock objects rather than just a simple array of strings.

The only part that the above tutorials won't help you with is storing an ArrayList of objects within an persistable object in Google DataStore.  I'm not sure if that is actually possible; you might have to store each of the object types separately and then programmatically retrieve **Classes** and **Books** related to a specific **Student** using GQL.

Answer (score 0):

You might want to check out [Gilead](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/) and it's [Adapter for Google AppEngine](http://noon.gilead.free.fr/gilead/index.php?mact=News,cntnt01,detail,0&cntnt01articleid=7&cntnt01returnid=15).  There's even a [sample project](http://gilead.svn.sourceforge.net/viewvc/gilead/samples/trunk/GWT/SampleAppEngine.JDO/).  I've gotten it working on my local machine in Eclipse, but I keep getting errors when it's deployed to GAE.

Comment: I tried it, spend two days figuring out that framework/library but had no luck :(. But thank you tho