# GWT RPC and persistent Java objects

Tags: gwt, google-cloud-datastore, gwt-rpc

First of all,

many thanks to Craig for the excellent answer below which I found very useful when searching my original issue...
**ref: [GWT Simple RPC use case problem : Code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237142/gwt-simple-rpc-use-case-problem-code-included)**

Building on this solution, how does one overcome the (seemingly GWT limitation) where if i leave my persistable object in **/shared** folder as Craig suggests... and **annotate** it as GWT tutorials suggest...

```
@PersistenceCapable
public class Employee {

@PrimaryKey
@Persistent(valueStrategy = IdGeneratorStrategy.IDENTITY)
private Key key;
```

GWT is seemingly unable to deal with  / import the com.google.appengine.datastore.key on the client side?

I have seen a few ugly hacks...but nothing elegant.

Any suggestions welcome,
Thanks

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Unfortunately, App Engine's `Key` class (and others) are *not* GWT-compatible. This means that you have to retrieve an object from the datastore, then translate it into a GWT-compatible POJO to send over GWT-RPC to the client.

I suggest looking into using the [objectify](http://code.google.com/p/objectify-appengine/) framework for App Engine. Not only is it a much simpler interface into the datastore, but the persistent objects it uses *are* GWT-compatible, so you can send them over GWT-RPC to your client.

Answer (score 2):

You can use the Key class in GWT code by adding these additional jar files:

http://www.resmarksystems.com/code/

- appengine-utils-client-1.0.jar
- appengine-utils-server-1.0.jar

This basically gives the GWT compiler a GWT-friendly version of the Key and other AppEngine classes. (like Text, Blob and User..)

To use:

- Add the appengine-utils-client-1.0.jar anywhere in your build path.
- Put the appengine-utils-server-1.0.jar to your WEB-INF/lib folder.

In your GWT module add the following:

```
<inherits name="com.resmarksystems.AppEngineDataTypes"/>
```

Comment: Hi, resmarksystems libraries deal with Key, Text, ShortBlob, Blob, Link, User, PostalAddress, PhoneNumber and Rating. Is there a way to deal with com.google.appengine.api.datastore.GeoPt in the same context (RPC, persistent Java objects)?

Answer (score 0):

If you don't need the Key object for something your key can be a Long or String which are easily serializable and thus work with standard GWT-RPC.

[Datastore keys](http://code.google.com/intl/sv-SE/appengine/docs/java/datastore/creatinggettinganddeletingdata.html#Keys)

Answer (score 0):

I think Google has just released a GWT library called requestfactory for this use-case.
[This is the link](http://code.google.com/webtoolkit/doc/latest/DevGuideRequestFactory.html)