# GWT returning custom objects that implement interfaces from external jars

Tags: java, gwt, rpc, gxt

I'm trying to implement an application that would read some path from the server and show it as a tree in web. For the client side I'm using Sencha GXT Tree that uses a TreeStore.

I saw this question that is very close to what I'm having as code:
[GWT Simple RPC use case problem : Code included](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2237142/gwt-simple-rpc-use-case-problem-code-included)
The difference on my side would be that my TestObject class is implementing also TreeStore.TreeNode along with Serializable. This TreeStore.TreeNode is located in the gxt-3.0.1.jar that I added both to buildpath and to classpath.

```
import java.util.List;
import java.io.Serializable;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.TreeStore;
import com.sencha.gxt.data.shared.TreeStore.TreeNode;

@SuppressWarnings("serial")
public class TestObject implements TreeStore.TreeNode<TestCase>, Serializable {
  public TestObject() {
    
  }
[...]
```

I'm trying to return from server side a TreeStore object containing the data about the content of the directories at the given path. But the execution of the async call fails with `java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: com/sencha/gxt/data/shared/TreeStore$TreeNode`

What should I do to have the server side to see this object that is actually more client side specific, given it comes from the gxt jar?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure the gxt jar is on the server classpath - it should be located in `WEB-INF/lib/` for the server to find it. Simply having it on the project classpath isn't enough to make sure that the war application can find it.