# GAE Datastore results to FlexTable using JDO

Tags: google-app-engine, gwt, jdo, gwt-rpc

This seems like a simple task, but somewhere in searching the docs- I've missed the connection.

I have a menu stored in GAE and can return the results of a query:

```
public String[] getMeals() throws NotLoggedInException {
    checkLoggedIn();
    PersistenceManager pm = getPersistenceManager();
    List<String> meals = new ArrayList<String>();

    try {
        Query q = pm.newQuery(Meal.class, "user == u");
        q.declareParameters("com.google.appengine.api.users.User u");
        q.setOrdering("createDate");
        List<Meal> myMeals = (List<Meal>) q.execute(getUser());

        for (Meal myMeal : myMeals) {
            meals.add(myMeal.getMealID());
        }
    } finally {
        pm.close();
    }
    return (String[]) meals.toArray(new String[0]);
}
```

With those results, I'd like to bind it to a FlexTable.  Using the stockwatcher sample, I've managed to get my ID bound to the FlexTable, but am missing the concept of how I tie the other fields in my result set to it.  (The fields I have in the GAE are mealID, mealType and mealDate)

From above, we can see that I'm tossing mealID into a List.
I also know that my other fields *must* exist in the query because I haven't done anything to filter them.  As a matter of fact, if I change my code to:

meals.Add(myMeal.getMealID(), myMeal.getMealType(), myMeal.getMealDate());

it returns all the data, but the flex table treats each item as a new row instead of the three fields on one row.

So my question is: how should I be capturing my records and sending them to my FlexTable so that I can bind the FlexTable to the resultset?

For reference, client side code:

```
private void loadMeals() {
    // load meals from server service MealService
    mealService.getMeals(new AsyncCallback<String[]>() {
        public void onFailure(Throwable error) {
            handleError(error);
        }
        public void onSuccess(String[] meals) {
            displayMeals(meals);
        }
    });

}

private void displayMeals(String[] meals) {
    for (String meal : meals) {
        displayMenu(meal, meal, meal);
    }
}
```

The flextable gets populated like this:

mealID  | mealType  | mealDate
   1    |     1     |      1
   2    |     2     |      2
   3    |     3     |      3

I *want* it to populate like this:

mealID  | mealType  | mealDate
   1    | Breakfast | 12/22/2012
   2    | Lunch     | 12/22/2012
   3    | Snack     | 12/23/2012

Thanks in advance for your input!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This question is a duplicate of [Problems passing class objects through GWT RPC](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/958879/problems-passing-class-objects-through-gwt-rpc)

Following the details in that link, and little hired help from oDesk got me going.
Main oversight was needing the entrypoint class in {appname}.gwt.xml and placing the model classes in shared packages.